# wildcard in jquery value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this question is silly, Please feel free to correct.

I am using the code below for a form validation. How can I use a wildcard so that flagL12, flagM52 and other form ids starting with flag are validated?

```
var flag = $('#flag').val();
    if(!new RegExp("^[0-9]{2}$").test(flag)){
        $('#require-msg').html("FLAG format invalid! <br>Only 2 digit Numbers allowed for FLAG");
        $('#modal_opener').click();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
```

I tried using ^ after flag but it does not work

```
    var flag = $('#flag^').val();
    if(!new RegExp("^[0-9]{2}$").test(flag)){
        $('#require-msg').html("FLAG format invalid! <br>Only 2 digit Numbers allowed for FLAG");
        $('#modal_opener').click();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: What you need wild card?

Comment: The attribute startsWith selector is: `$('[id^=flag]')` but your other code doesn't really make sense so you should provide a minimalistic sample replicating your issue. You would probably use: `if($('[id^=flag]').filter(function(){return !new RegExp("^[0-9]{2}$").test(this.value)}).length) {$('#require-msg').html("FLAG format invalid! <br>Only 2 digit Numbers allowed for FLAG");}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use,

```
$("[id^='flag']")
```

This will select all the elements whose id starts with 'flag'

Comment: thanks, this works